# How to make polymorphism in java when using basic types like int?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am a new hand of Java programming, so if there is anything misused, remind and excuse me.
I can make polymorphism when dealing with class types, say:

```
    class A{}
    class B{}

    void method(Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof A) {}
    else if (obj instance of B){}
    else {}
}
```

I can pass different classes to call different part of method(), but when dealing with basic types like int, it is not inherited from Object.

I know actually this is not strict polymorphism, because there is not override. Maybe, generic programming is a more proper name, but I don't know whether this is right.

Comment: Polymorphism is rather not you can make. It's behaviour of language, which allows you to treat given object as various object types dependent of the context.

Comment: What do you think is a better way to express my point?

Comment: You can use the class Integer which extends Number which extends Object. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: I think you want your method to act in different ways when you call it with different simple types. Don't you? Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can define few methods with the same name and different argument types like that:

```
void method(int a) {}
void method(long a) {}
void method(double a) {}
```

As @ByteCommander mentioned it's called **overloading**
I think it's what you meant. In this case when you call:

```
int a = 1; method(a);
```

you will execute first method defined. And so on...

Comment: Also: Boxed integers.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I think question is not clear, but author meant to have one method with few types of arguments.

Comment: This technique is called method overloading, isn't it? But what is the definition of Polymorphism instead?

Comment: polymorphism= extends class+method overload+ base class reference pointing to child class reference; This formula is from a Chinese java tutorial.

Comment: good! This is what I want, I don't know I can do so because I used to think there will be name confilicts within one class.

Comment: Nice to hear I could help. It's called overloading and it's good to know that language feature. Don't forget to upvote my answer and mark it as good. By the way, it was not very easy to understand your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do what you are talking about (which isn't quite polymorphism) with basic data types, you could try to use Integers, instead of ints. ints are raw data, which are stored by their value. Integer is a class, and has all the functionality of one (plus auto-boxing/unboxing, but don't worry about that).

Because Integer is a class, you can extend it and do what your are talking about with the instanceof stuff.

There are also (Long)s, (Double)s, (Boolean)s, et cetera